# How do I get the a tag to wrap the_title when showing only the logged-in author's post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am ALMOST there with this, but need help with the final piece. I am trying to show only a link to an author's post after they log in. It works, but the snippet below displays the post title as plain text, then generates an empty `<a>` tag after the post title instead of wrapping the post title with the `<a>`. The link in the `<a>` is correct, just not wrapping the post title. What am I missing?

```
<?php
                    
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'team_fundraiser',
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'author' => $user_id
    );                       

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $team_link .= '<a href="' .get_permalink(). '">'.the_title().'</a>';
    endwhile;

    echo $team_link;
                
?>
```

The output looks like this....

```
<div>
    
    "My Awesome Post"
    <a href="http://localhost/mysite/my-awesome-post/"></a>

</div>
```

How do I get the `<a>` to wrap the post title?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `the_title` with `get_the_title`. [the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) echoes out the title by default, hence why the title is appearing before the link. [get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) will return you the title as a value.

So change the line inside the while loop to this

```php
$team_link .= '<a href="' . get_permalink(). '">'. get_the_title() . '</a>';
```

I'd also recommend wrapping the `get_the_title` function in the `esc_html` function ([WP Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/)) and the hyperlink in the `esc_url` function ([WP Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/)) to ensure you don't get any HTML/JS outputted along with the title and link.

Would end up like this:

```php
$team_link .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ). '">'. esc_html( get_the_title() ) . '</a>';
```